# using php foreach for data in an email

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

So I have a query that pulls data from the database and into a table, it also goes into an array like so:

```
<table class="list">
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Username </th>
        <th> Most Steps</th>
        <th> Average Steps </th>
        <th> Total Steps </th>
      </tr>

        <?php //get info for scores in the league
         if ($result = $link->query("SELECT SUM(DISTINCT step_count.steps) as total,  logins.nickname, MAX(step_count.steps) as maxsteps, ROUND(AVG (DISTINCT step_count.steps)) as average, logins.Email as email
            FROM step_count
            INNER JOIN logins on
              step_count.unique_id=logins.unique_id
            INNER JOIN leagues ON
              leagues.unique_id=logins.unique_id
          WHERE step_count.date BETWEEN '$info[start_date]' AND '$info[end_date]'
            GROUP BY logins.unique_id
            ORDER BY `total` DESC
          ", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))
          $rank = 1;


          //add data to an arry for email use
          $leaguedata = array();

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              $leaguedata[] = $row; ?>


          <tr>
           <td><?php echo $rank++; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['nickname']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['maxsteps']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['average']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>
          </tr>

                <?php }  $result->close(); ?>

           </table>
```

I then have an area in which I send an email with the results once the league has finished:

```
<?php //if admin and the date has past, change active to 0
       if ($info['role'] == "ADMIN") {
         if ($info['end_date'] < date("Y-m-d")) {

         $endleague = "UPDATE leagues SET active = 0
          WHERE joincode='$joincode'";

          mysqli_query($link,$endleague);

          echo "<h3><br/>This league has now ended, results will be sent to everyone via email!</h3>";

          //send league ending information
          $endrank = 1;

          $subject = "$league_name has ended!";
            $body="Results are in and these were the final scores:".PHP_EOL;
            $body.="$endrank++".PHP_EOL; 

            $headers = "From: localhost";

          foreach ($leaguedata as $email){
                    mail($email['email'], $subject, $body, $headers); }


        }
          } ?>
```

I am unsure on how the foreach loop works in the email body itself and also how to get $endrank++ to work inside the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `endrank` line could be:

```
$subject = "$league_name has ended!";
$body="Results are in and these were the final scores:".PHP_EOL;
$endrank++;
$body.=$endrank.PHP_EOL;
```

As for the `foreach` statement, lets say you want to add some data from your rows:

```
// Keep anything static between all emails outside of your loop
$endrank = 1;
$endrank++;
$subject = "$league_name has ended!";
$headers = "From: localhost";

// For your big array of all your rows ($leaguedata), do something for each row
foreach ($leaguedata as $row){

    // Initialise your new text body
    $body;

    // Access anything from each row as $row['something']
    $body .= "Hello, $row['nickname']".PHP_EOL;

    // Pop in the league results which are common to all the emails
    $body .="Results are in and these were the final scores:".PHP_EOL;
    $body .=$endrank.PHP_EOL;

    // Send the email
    mail($row['email'], $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

Comment: The $endrank works great thank you! And as for the foreach statement, I mean for inside the actual email like where the $endrank is

Comment: Well ```$endrank ``` is being placed inside ```$body``` which is just 2 strings joined together and is effectively the content of your email. When you say you're not sure how it works - does it work, or if not what is it you're trying to find out?

Comment: I want to add the different $rows in the array into the email so that it basically sends the users the results from this league so something like:

foreach ($leaguedata as $nickname) {
$body.="Name: $nickname['nickname']".PHP_EOL; }

Comment: Ah much clearer, I have updated my answer to show how to use your DB variables in each email. It would also make sense to do a conventional ```for``` loop for this sort of job